# Multiple Go in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

I'd like to write a stored procedure and store it in a SQL Server database. The procedure is supposed to remove all tables regardless of dependency constraints.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_clear_db AS
BEGIN
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DROP TABLE ?';
END
```

However, when I call `sp_helptext @objname = 'dbo.sp_clear_db'`, only the first exec statement is shown. I assume in order to execute the first function, a `GO` has to be called. But a `GO` as part of the stored procedure definition won't work either. Does anyone know a way to fix this? Maybe there is another better option to achieve the same...

Cheers,
Max

Comment: remove all tables? why not just drop the database?

Comment: Because the application running the code is connected to that database. Any change in that would be impractical.

Comment: and what sort of crazy application needs to drop all tables??  So, disconnect and reconnect. what's the big deal?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you neeed to drop all tables (i.e. rather than ask for help with a perceived solution)

Comment: It's a unit test (=crazy application). I'd imagine this sort of thing happens very often...

Comment: <pedant>actually, that would make it an integration test. </pedant>

Comment: As I said, it's a unit test, not an integration test. If you can't help that's fine.

Comment: By common definition, if you are talking to an external system, it is an integration test.

Comment: Who said the database is an external system. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing. The very first sentence states it clearly.

Comment: You said so here: "Because the application running the code is connected to that database".

Comment: Have you consider restoring a known database backup (a known snapshot of the data if you will)? This is a common way to solve this problem.

Comment: This might be difficult to accomplish from within the unit test setup method. The unit test really assumes an empty database.

Comment: Another way to solve your issue would be to add the `create database xx` to the setup of your test suite and drop the database when testing is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have "GO" in a stored procedure. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)  GO is used by SQL Query analyser to separate statements into "Batches" which are then sent to SQL server. So you'd need to make two separate calls, one for the ALTER calls and one for the DROP.

Ideally you would just call "DROP DATABASE" unless you were trying to keep your stored procs and then re-create the tables.

Another solution would be to use a cursor to loop through each row in sys.tables where type='U' and generate some dynamic sql to remove the contraints and drop the table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sp_helptext. Use [OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) or [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx)